# spacemacs, web-mode, cannot indent

Tags: indentation, spacemacs, web-mode

I am using spacemacs. When writing .html file, it shows that it is in `web-mode`. I want to indent, press `TAB`, but nothing happened. So I can only use `SPC` to indent.

I added

```
(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
(setq web-mode-indent-style 4)
```

to .spacemacs file, but it did not work. I also tried

```
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 4)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 4)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 4)
  (setq web-mode-indent-style 4)
  )
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
```

But it did not work either.

So what I should do to make it indent using `TAB`?

From `C-h k tab`:

```
<tab> runs the command spacemacs/emmet-expand, which is an interactive Lisp
function in ‘../../../html/funcs.el’.

It is bound to <tab>, TAB, <hybrid-state> <tab>, <hybrid-state> TAB,
<emacs-state> <tab>, <emacs-state> TAB, <insert-state> <tab>, <insert-state>
TAB.

(spacemacs/emmet-expand)
```

Comment: Check to see what the `tab` key actually does: hit `C-h k tab` and report back.

Comment: You should probably add the rest of the docstring for `spacemacs/emmet-expand` in case anyone knows what it does.  My best guess, though, is that the `tab` key does not indent because that's not what the command does.

Comment: @Dan Thank you for your suggestions.